# Prefill WooCommerce price field when adding a new product in admin area

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I prefill the price field in the woo-commerce edit product page?

The price fields, I want to prefill are (Minimum) & (Maximum) price fields. These fields are generated by the "Name your price" plugin from WooCommerce.

Screenshot:
[image]

The label for minimum price is **_min_price**

The label for the maximum price is **_maximum_price**

I want the "Minimum Price" field to be prefilled with **"10"** & the "Maximum Price" field should be **"250"**

I've tried using the following code, but it didn't work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 
                'prefill_min_max' );
                function prefill_min_max(){

                ?>

    <script>
        (function($){
            $('input[name=_min_price]').val('10');
            $('input[name=_maximum_price]').val('250');  
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <?php

}
```

Comment: Do i need to use any other funtion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs improvement and fixes, here is the fixed and updated code.

```php
/**
 * Hook script in admin footer.
 */
add_action(
    'admin_footer',
    function () {
        // Get the current screen ID.
        $screen    = get_current_screen();
        $screed_id = $screen->id ? $screen->id : '';

        // We only want to load our script on the product edit page screen.
        if ( ! in_array( $screed_id, array( 'product' ), true ) ) {
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            (function ($) {
                // Get the minimum price element.
                $min_price = $(".product_data input[name=_min_price]");
                // Check if the element exists and is empty. don't wanna make the change on an already filled value.
                if ($min_price.length && $min_price.val() === "") {
                    $min_price.val(10);
                }
                
                // Get the maximum price element.
                $maximum_price = $(".product_data input[name=_maximum_price]");
                // Check if the element exists and is empty. don't wanna make the change on an already filled value.
                if ($maximum_price.length && $maximum_price.val() === "") {
                    $maximum_price.val(250);
                }
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    }
);
```

Comment: Note: make sure input names are correct, in `val()` function pass the number value, not the string, if you pass a value with quotes it's a string. and it might not work for the number-based input.